# How to limit the inline ForeignKey queryset to the instance itself in Django admin

Tags: python, django, admin, inline

I have 5 models  and their relations are as follows:

```
class A(models.Model):
    pass


class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)


class C(models.Model):
    b = models.ManyToManyField(B)


class D(models.Model):
    pass


class I(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    b = models.ForeignKey(B)
    c = models.ForeignKey(C)
    d = models.ForeignKey(D)
```

I decide to use the django admin

```
class IAdminInline(admin.TabularInline):
    pass

class DAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [IAdminInline, ]
```

The admin page makes a lot queries,if too many I instances are related to D, which is time consuming. So I disable the  Django default actions by setting the formfield_for_foreignkey:

```
 def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        field = super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
        field.choices = [] # django will not make any queries if set choices
```

Instead, I use ajax to get the corresponding data, and use javascript to render the select widgets and bind actions , which make it easier to add data since these widgets are related to each other. Page loads faster but problem is that, the above code would clear I instances initial values that are apparently already existing in the change view page.

I want to ask **how can I render the existing inline object select widgets to their own values? Does Django provide any functions to handle this?**

I haven't find any solutions other than using ajax to render the apparently existing values all by myself.